# How to create TimestampType column in spark from string

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I have some datas contained in an Array of String like below (just for exemple):

```
val myArray = Array("1499955986039", "1499955986051", "1499955986122")
```

I want to map my list to an array of Timestamp, in order to create an RDD (myRdd) then create a dataframe like this

```
val df = createdataframe(myRdd, StructType(StructField("myTymeStamp", TimestampType,true)
```

My question is not how to create the Rdd, but how to replace string by millisecond timestamp. Do you have any idea? Thanks

Comment: keep it string when you define and cast it to timestamp using the in-built functions later.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Use [`java.sql.Timestamp`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/sql/Timestamp.html):

```
val myArray = Array("1499955986039", "1499955986051", "1499955986122")
import java.sql.Timestamp    
import org.apache.spark.sql.Row
import org.apache.spark.sql.types.{StructType, StructField, TimestampType}

val rdd = sc.parallelize(myArray).map(s => Row(new Timestamp(s.toLong)))

val schema = StructType(Array(StructField("myTymeStamp", TimestampType, true)))

spark.createDataFrame(rdd, schema)
// res25: org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame = [myTymeStamp: timestamp]
```

Answer (score 4):

You dont need to convert to timestamp before,
You just convert to long and you can use schema to convert to tymestamp while creating dataframe as below

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.Row

val myArray = Array("1499955986039", "1499955986051", "1499955986122")

val myrdd = spark.sparkContext.parallelize(myArray.map(a => Row(a.toLong)))

val df = spark.createDataFrame(myrdd, StructType(Seq(StructField("myTymeStamp", TimestampType,true))))
```

Otherwise you can just create a dataframe from String and cast to timestamp later as below

```
val df = spark.createDataFrame(myrdd, StructType(Seq(StructField("myTymeStamp", StringType,true))))

//cast myTymeStamp from String to Long and to timestamp
df.withColumn("myTymeStamp", $"myTymeStamp".cast(LongType).cast(TimestampType))
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: how to create an individual variable of type Timestamp from date?